# Reversed datapoints on Flot graph data

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a ton of json data to display, that unfortunately, instead of being in the format `[x,y]` which is the flot default, it is in the format `[y,x`], now, I've tried doing this:

```
var row = {
    data: $data.datapoints,
    label: $data.target,
    yaxis: 2,
};
```

And other combinatios of xaxis, yaxis 1 and 2 values, but nothing changes, I really need my lines to be horizontal and not vertical.

The header of flot is:

```
*! Javascript plotting library for jQuery, v. 0.7.
```

Flot is at:
http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: What do you mean your data is in the format y,x?  Is this already in javascript array?

Answer (score 3):

You can just iterate over the whole array.

```
var initialArray = [
 [2,1],
 [4,3],
 [6,5],
 [8,7]
];

var cleanArray = [];

var i=0;
for (i=0;i<initialArray.length;i++){
  cleanArray[i] = [initialArray[i][1], initialArray[i][0],]
}

/*Array is now:
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6],
  [7,8]
];

*/
```

Bonus points if you make it a function. There's more elegant ways to solve this.

Comment: Well, thats why I said I have a ton of data, reversing it manually might be expensive, depending on the graph, besides the flot API seems to suggest this is possible so I might be missing the right conf or it might be a bug.

Comment: @tomato Why haven't you linked to the flot plugin or something? There's literally thousands of jQuery plugins. How much is "a ton" anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was well known, a ton varies, cause I am drawing monitoring values for servers, I've seen 5k values once but I think it is not the top level

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/yLBBD/ here is another example of @Incognito solution. except I have reversed the original array. not sure if this is faster. do some perf tests. this test has two arrays with 100 000 points in each. still renders fairly quickly for me. I have added this as an answer.

Comment: On my machine it takes 0.021 seconds to flip 50,000 array pairs. http://pastebin.com/QhFpyKpA

Comment: now, for each graph count about 3,4 series and draw 6-8 graphs of the management interface of the monitoring system, that plus the ajaxy reload, my browser is getting some serious load when I try that.

Comment: Then fix your data or use a library that can deal with broken data.

Comment: Well, the library claims to do that, thats why I asked t osee if somebody familiar could resolve it, I was already aware that I could reverse the data myself. Also I cannot fix the data as it is coming from 3rd party Graphite, I might try hacking into flot.

Comment: @tomato Which part of the doc are you reading? I didn't see it in there.

Comment: [API](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/API.txt) The "xaxis" and "yaxis" options specify which axis to use. The axes
are numbered from 1 (default), so { yaxis: 2} means that the series
should be plotted against the second y axis.

Answer (score 1):

working from @Inconito's answer... here is another way to 'reverse' the values in the array.

```
function fixData(d /* data array */) {
    d.forEach(function(i,el) {
        return [el[1],el[0]];
    });
}
/* example data generation */
var d1 = [], d2 = [];
for( var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
    var y = i,
        x = i;
    d1.push([y,x]);
    d2.push([y/2,x/4]);
}
/* reverse the data */
fixData(d1);
fixData(d2);
/* plot it */
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1,d2]);​
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/yLBBD/)